# Как использовать enum для таблицы отношений?

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enum

У меня есть статичные данные с правами, мне не нужно их хранить в базе данных и создавать таблицу с разрешениями, я хочу использовать Enum

```
enum permission: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

Что нужно сделать в моделях, чтобы я мог при вызове использовать Enum для роли:

```
Role.first.permission
=>"create"
```

I have migration:

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
        t.string :name
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompaniesRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies_roles do |t|
      t.integer :company_id
      t.integer :role_id
      t.integer :permission
    end
  end
end
```

[schema in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J1FQ.jpg)

Все связи многие ко многим.

Comment: Не очень поняла вопрос - поле `permission` находится у вас в связующей таблице `companies_roles`, но вы хотите добавить такое же поле к модели Role? Мне кажется, будет лучше, если вы объясните, зачем вы это делаете - возможно, проблема решается по-другому

Comment: А вообще очень рекомендую для авторизации использовать [cancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) или [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit)

Comment: @Василиса Эта логика делаеться для Пандита. Что бы разграничить доступ, задача хранить конкретный пермишен, к примеру на <удаление> для конкретной компании и роли. В Таблице Ролей будут храниться некая интерпритация к контролерам, и нужно хранить информацию еще к Экшенам(это поле Permission). В итоге зайдя в полиси пандита я должен проверять - компания имеет доступ и на что именно доступ на запись или на чтение?!

Answer (score 0):

В моем проекте это реализовано через разные роли, по типу

```
employee_admin
employee_manager
employee_viewer
```

И на мой взгляд это более простой вариант. Но если вы хотите так, то вам нужно будет искать CompanyRole по айдишнику пользователя и компания и смотреть в её `permission`

```
CompanyRole.find_by(company_id: record.id, user_id: user.id).permission
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у Вас роли статические, у меня динамическая структура, с постоянно меняющимеся правами для ролей. Компании привязаны к пользователям, обращения к вложенности через пользователя несущественно пока что. В коде на данный момент я использую именно такого типа форму поиска обращаясь к таблице связей, как вы и написали. 
Мне нужно получить форму обращения на подобии этой [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687704/habtm-with-ar-enum-scope) с использованием явной адрессации к структуре через has_and_belongs_to_many или has_many.

Comment: @JurgenMeier Если компании и роли связаны и у вас через `has_many through`, то вы можете запросить `Company.company_roles.distinct.pluck(:permission)`. Или я всё ещё не понимаю вашей проблемы?